# How to recycle appool when IIS getting slow response by using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, devops

I am trying to write a script to check health of my web application's health status. Forexample if I couldn't get message in 10 seconds I have to recycle my apppool by using Powershell.Or except 200-ok codes, my app pool should recycled.

Please look at below code and ERROR:

```py
# Load IIS module:
Import-Module WebAdministration
while ($true) {
    write-host 'Runnig For Check app.xxx.com ...'

# First we create the request.
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('https://app.xxx.com/')
Try
{
# We then get a response from the site.
$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

# We then get the HTTP code as an integer.
$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
    Write-Host "Site is OK!"
}
Else {
    Write-Host "The Site may be down, please check!"
    Restart-WebAppPool -Name "app.xxx.com"
}
}
Catch
{
     Stop-WebAppPool -Name "app.xxx.com"
     Restart-WebAppPool -Name "app.xxx.com"
}

# Finally, we clean up the http request by closing it.
$HTTP_Response.Close()

 Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
}
```

Error:

> Restart-WebAppPool : You have to start stopped object before
>   restarting it. At C:\Scripts\CheckHealthHaydigo.ps1:25 char:6
>   +      Restart-WebAppPool -Name "app.xxx.com"
>   +      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Restart-WebAppPool], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.RestartAppPoolCommand

Comment: Why not just run `Start-WebAppPool` when it has stopped instead of trying to restart it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you should check the status of the app pool before trying to restart it.

```
if ((Get-WebAppPoolState -Name "app.xxx.com").Value -eq "Stopped") {
    Start-WebAppPool -Name "app.xxx.com"
}
else {
    Restart-WebAppPool -Name "app.xxx.com"
}
```